# Rails update_attribute not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2, update-attribute

i need update a single record attribute but i can´t. alumno_id is foreign key of model 'alumno'. the code show the records and if submit 'Aceptar' in one record, need a change the attribute estado to 1

in Model

```
class Postulacion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ramo, :estado, :alumno_id
  belongs_to :alumno
end
```

in View

```
<h1>Lista de Postulaciones</h1>
<% @postulaciones.each do |p| %>
<% @id = p.id %>
<%= @id %>
<p>
<td><%= Alumno.find(p.alumno_id).full_name%></td>
<td><%='=> '+ p.ramo %></td>
<td><% if p.estado == 0 %>
    <%= 'Pendiente =>' %>
    <%= form_tag :action => 'aceptar' do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Aceptar' %></p>
    <%end%>
    <%else%>
    <%='=>  Aceptado' %>
    <%end%>
</td>
</p>
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
class ListadoController < ApplicationController
  def listar   
    @postulaciones = Postulacion.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @postulaciones }
    end  
  end
 def aceptar
  @postulacion = Postulacion.where(id: @id).first #Edit
      @postulacion.estado = 1 #Edit
      @postulacion.save #Edit
  redirect_to "/"
```

end
    end

Error "undefined method `update_attribute' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
 @postulacion = Postulacion.where(alumno_id: @id )
```

You are declaring `@postulacion` as a collection, not as a single instance.  You can fix this by calling `.first`:

```
 @postulacion = Postulacion.where(alumno_id: @id ).first
```

Or by using `find_by` instead of `where`:

```
 @postulacion = Postulacion.find_by(alumno_id: @id )
```

One other thing - this code isn't checking for the possibility that the Postulacion instance might not exist.  You should add some logic to handle this...

Comment: @11Rodrigo - the same error?  Please post updated code with stack trace of error.

Comment: ""undefined method `update_column' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3b1a6c8> " the same error

Comment: @11Rodrigo - you didn't update the code using `first` or `find_by` as suggested.  If you don't use the suggested fix, why do you expect a better result? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `@postulacion` variable holds `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of single `ActiveRecord` object. Try:

```
def acceptar
  @postulacion = Postulacion.find_by_alumino_id(@id)
  # ...
end
```

or, if you'd be using Rails 4:

```
@postulacion = Postulacion.find_by(alumino_id: @id)
```

Comment: Just an FYI - `find_by_attribute` has been deprecated (although it will still work in Rails 3.x)

Comment: @PinnyM I know - but it's tagged with ruby-on-rails-3.2 tag. Thanks anyway.